# Can't access protected routes with Firebase onAuthStateChanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, react-router

Im quite new to React but i'm trying to create a todo application for myself, now I am running into the issue that my application automatically pushes me to the Login page as I wanted but I can't access any other pages since it refreshes everything.

As far as my understanding goes my AuthContext.jsx uses the useEffect hook so it runs onauthstatechanged and fills in the user state before rendering any page within the context.

This is my AuthContext:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

import { auth } from "../api/firebase.config";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setCurrentUser] = useState("");

  function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut() {
    console.log("uitloggen");
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setCurrentUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signUp, logIn }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

This my ProtectedRoutes:

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./src/context/AuthContext";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

And last but not least my main.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../ProtectedRoutes";
import Layout from "./layout/Layout";
import Companies from "./pages/Companies";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";
import Calendar from "./pages/Calendar";
import Tasks from "./pages/Tasks";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="companies" element={<Companies />} />
            <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
            <Route path="calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
            <Route path="tasks" element={<Tasks />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Should I save the user locally  to avoid this from happening, I thought that onAuthStateChanged combined with useEffect would make that obsolete. I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

I tried entering pages directly from the browser by typing in the url of the page, that did not work while it should. Someone should not have to login every time he opens another page.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what "now I am running into the issue that my application automatically pushes me to the Login page as I wanted but I can't access any other pages since it refreshes everything." means. Can you clarify what the issue is? What is "refreshed"? Can you clarify your ***exact*** steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for quick answer. Whats happening is that if I for example refresh the browsers it kicks me out of the dashboard back to the /login page and also if I try to reach another page via the url, "localhost:3000/tasks" for example it does exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese, this wasnt the solution but it did help me. The issue was that I defined an empty string as the initial user state and the logOut function was not available in the AuthContext so i could not test properly :).  Feels good to figure this kind of stuff out haha.

Comment: I see... I figured it was a duplicate since an empty string `""` is considered a falsey value so the ternary operator was assuming it was the "unauthenticated" state. Glad to help either way. Cheers and good luck!